# Assets folder not served from a Node.JS AWS elastic beanstalk app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have successfully deployed an Angular app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but it isn't loading any of the assets (css, js, images, etc).

http://jlt-website.ca-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

According to their documentation, I can create an `nginx.conf` file with this content:

```
location /assets/ {
    alias /var/app/current/dist/apps/website/browser/assets/;
}
```

Or I can create a `static-files.config` file in an `.ebextensions` folder:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /assets: /var/app/current/dist/apps/website/browser/assets
    /assets/images: /var/app/current/dist/apps/website/browser/assets/images
```

None of these things work.

When I console.log my `distFolder` variable in the Express server I get the correct path to my files: `/var/app/current/dist/apps/website/browser` but nothing is resolving.

Any other ideas?

Screenshots:

[Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fjfO.png)
[Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gols.png)

Created a nginx.conf file and an elastic beanstalk static asset configuration.